# Remove content of html code in PHP like <p></p>

Tags: php, regex

i want to remove html tag

inside content.

```
//Input like these

<p class="wp-caption-text">Hello World</p><p style="text-align: justify;">Welcome to PHP</p>

//Output like

<p>Hello World</p><p>Welcome to PHP</p>
```

What i have to use to solve these ? please any one help me.

```
//I used these regex but it's not completely work.
$plaintext = preg_replace('%style="[^"]+"%i', '', $plaintext);
//what i have to add here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like below,

```
$plaintext = preg_replace('%<p\K\s+[^<>]*%i', '', $plaintext);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xL5mA6/4)

- `\K` discards the previously matched characters.
- `\s+` Matches one or more spaces.
- `[^<>]*` Matches any character but not of `<` or `>` zero or more times.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=<p)([^>]+)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/27

```
$re = "/(?<=<p)([^>]+)/m";
$str = "<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">Hello World</p><p style=\"text-align: justify;\">Welcome to PHP</p>";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```